# Como incrementar de 0 a 10 dentro de um setInterval em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(function()
{
    var x = 0; 
    x++; 
    console.log(x);},
    1000);
}
```

Comment: Podes explicar qual a funcionalidade que queres alcançar?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode chamar `clearInterval()` depois de 10 chamadas:

```
var x = 0;
var intervalo = setInterval(function () {
   console.log(x);
    if (++x === 10) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalo);
    }
 }, 1000);
```

Se você quiser evitar variáveis globais, uma boa melhoria seria:

```
function setIntervalo(delay, iteracoes) {
    var x = 0;
    var intervalo = window.setInterval(function () {

       console.log(x);

       if (x++ === iteracoes) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalo);
       }
    }, delay);
}
```

Depois basta chamar `setInvervalo`:

```
setIntervalX(1000, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção é usar `setTimeout` para simular o comportamento de `setInterval` e ter uma função que determina quando deve acabar.

```
function setIntervalDelayed(delay, interval, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(cb()){
            setIntervalDelayed(interval, interval, cb);
        }
    }, delay);
}

setIntervalDelayed(0, 1000, function(){
    return x++ != 10;
})
```